# How to scan through all the rows and split into different file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

My data looks like

```
Message    ID      ParentID
Parent     123     
Child      234     123
Parent     333     
Child      567     333
Child      789     333
Child      100     333 
Parent     444     
Child      446     444
Child      555     444
Child      111     444
Parent     5555     
Child      446     5555
Child      555     5555
Child      111     5555
Parent     456     
Child      112     456
Child      334     456
Child      110     456
```

I have the CSV file created with this data. how ever, I need to split the data into multiple files. 
Logic  is:
 Parent and its child for 3 parents should be in file 1. 4th parent and 5th parent will fall under file 2. This is just not for 5 parents. It could be random. I would like to split the file with 3 parents and their respective child. 
If my file has 31 parents. I should create 31/3 = 10 files with 3 parents and 1 file with remaining 1 parent.

```
Sample1_file:
Message    ID      ParentID
Parent     123     
Child      234     123
Parent     333     
Child      567     333
Child      789     333
Child      100     333 
Parent     444     
Child      446     444
Child      555     444
Child      111     444

Sample2_file:
Message    ID      ParentID
Parent     5555     
Child      446     5555
Child      555     5555
Child      111     5555
Parent     456     
Child      112     456
Child      334     456
Child      110     456
```

I have a code for splitting the file based on line number.

```
#split test
param([String]$p1)

$sw = new-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start()
$filename = $p1
$rootName = $p1 -replace ".csv", "_"
$ext = "csv"
$header = get-content $filename -TotalCount 1 

$linesperFile = 90001 
$filecount = 1
$reader = $null
try{
    $reader = [io.file]::OpenText($filename)
    try{
        "Creating file number $filecount"
        $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
        $filecount++
        $linecount = 0

        while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
            "Reading $linesperFile"
            while( ($linecount -lt $linesperFile) -and ($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true)){
                $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine());
                $linecount++
            }

            if($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
                "Closing file"
                $writer.Dispose();

                "Creating file number $filecount"
                $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
                $writer.WriteLine($header);
                $filecount++
                $linecount = 0
            }
        }
    } finally {
        $writer.Dispose();
    }
} finally {
    $reader.Dispose();
}
$sw.Stop()

Write-Host "Split complete in " $sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds "seconds"
```

Can someone help me with implementing this parent-child logic?

Answer (score 0):

Not speed optimized approach is:

- Grouping data by parentID,
- iterate groups and count, calculate filename,
- get parent for group
- if new name Export, else Export -append
- Export -append current group

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_57715743.ps1
# simulate reading data from external csv file
$Data = @"
Message,ID,ParentID
Parent,123,
Child,234,123
Parent,333,
Child,567,333
Child,789,333
Child,100,333
Parent,444,
Child,446,444
Child,555,444
Child,111,444
Parent,5555,
Child,446,5555
Child,555,5555
Child,111,5555
Parent,456,
Child,112,456
Child,334,456
Child,110,456
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-csv

$DstFolder = 'x:\where\ever'
$PCount=2
$Data | Group-Object ParentID | Where {$_.Group.ParentID -gt 0} | Sort-Object {[int]$_.name}| ForEach-Object {
    $FileName = Join-Path $DstFolder ('sample{0}_file.csv' -f [int]($PCount++ / 3))
    $Parent = $Data | Where-Object ID -eq $_.Name 
    if ($FileName -ne $PrevFile){
        $Parent | Export-Csv $FileName -NoTypeInformation
    } else {
        $Parent | Export-Csv $FileName -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    $PrevFile=$FileName
    $_.Group | Export-Csv $FileName -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Aside from integer sort exactly your described output:

```
> import-csv .\sample2_file.csv                                                                                                     
Message ID   ParentID
------- --   --------
Parent  456
Child   112  456
Child   334  456
Child   110  456
Parent  5555
Child   446  5555
Child   555  5555
Child   111  5555
```

Comment: thank you . i will try this code.. but how to export csv to certain folder?

Comment: See changed answer with `$DstFolder`

Comment: I have a csv file and have to read it instead of passing the data . I tried with $Data= Import-Csv "Path" and also with get contents filename. Both are throwing error. $Data should have my data from csv. is there a way?

Comment: `$Data= Import-Csv "Path"` should do, do you need to specify a delimiter or encoding?

Comment: $Data= Import-Csv "\\PPPPP\dts\data\fghjj\Files\Get-ChildItem *.csv". i was looking for file pattern instead of actual file in the folder. can you please tell me what is the mistake here?